# Using Bootstrap’s Push/Pull not working as I expected?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I’m trying to get an understanding on how Bootstrap’s Push/Pull in a Grid works. What I have is a page that on a Mobile version I would like to have an image on top of some text but when viewing on a large monitor I would like the text to the left and image to the right.

Asking some questions about it, I was told to look at the Push/Pull in Bootstrap’s Grid.

Then looking at some articles and examples I came up with the plunker below. Looking at it from a mobile first stand point I put the image on top of the text. However, I must be missing something because it will work as expected mobile but on large screen it does pull the image to the right and push the text to the left but it’s like they are on their own rows. The text on the left is not pulled up to the top to be level with the image. In addition, when it’s on the large screen the text is just a little too far to the left.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-push-5">
      <img src="..">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-pull-7">
      <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing 
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[plnkr.co/edit/6Gm7Hvq3h6xINV7540LQ?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Gm7Hvq3h6xINV7540LQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `col-sm-push` and `col-sm-pull`, and set the appropriate width for the columns.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-push-5">
      <img src="..">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-pull-7">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/iEvMZPDTk4)

Comment: See, that's what's confusing me. The way I'm reading this is that intially in sm mode the left column=7 and then right column=5. Wouldn't I want sm to be the full width of the Grid? And then it's not until the size gets to a md or lg that it would start using the push/pull? So why wouldn't I use use md or lg to let the browser know what to do when it's that size?

Comment: In this case `sm` means `sm` and up. `sm`, `md` and `lg` are ALL implied here. Columns automatically stack at the smallest (xs) or mobile breakpoint. Basically col-xs-12 is always implied which it why it's not used here because you want full width on xs. You only use `col-xs-*` when you DONT want them stacked full width on mobile.

Comment: Here's a very [helpful article on the Bootstrap grid](https://medium.com/wdstack/how-the-bootstrap-grid-really-works-471d7a089cfc)

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on the version you are using, for bootstrap 4 and above
 there is feature`order`.
 IT is always up to you to decide the order as per the viewport or I say device size
available for push-pull you can use that like this ...happy coding refer the [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#order)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 order-md-2 order-sm-1"  >
       <img src="..">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-10 order-md-1 order-sm-2 ">
      <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummying text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing 
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```